# Check if folder exists in the S3 bucket and create a folder if not

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to write a code wherein in the S3 bucket I want to check if the folder exists and if not, I want to create the folder. Following is my code.

```
def checkiffolderexists(bucket:str, path:str) -> bool:

    s3 = boto3.Session(profile_name='saml').client('s3')
    if not path.endswith('/'):
        path = path + '/'
        print(path)
    resp = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=path, Delimiter='/', MaxKeys=1)
    return 'Contents' in resp
```

I am passing the following arguments to this method created.

```
checkiffolderexists('star-mi-qa-ctset-delta-us-east-1','star-mi-qa-ctset-delta-us-east-1/vendor=ctset/type=own_v5/year=2022/month=10/day=01')
```

star-mi-qa-ctset-delta-us-east-1 is my bucket name and inside that I want to check if day=01/ folder is present or not. If not, I want to create that folder in the same path which I have passed to the method. The problem here is even if the folder exists there, the method is returning me false. Any mistake I am doing while passing the arguments to the method or in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys that match the Delimiter will not show up in the `Contents`.

From the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects):

> Causes keys that contain the same string between the prefix and the first occurrence of the delimiter to be rolled up into a single result element in the CommonPrefixes collection. **These rolled-up keys are not returned elsewhere in the response**.

(Emphasis mine.)

Calling the method without this parameter will work:

```
resp = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=path, MaxKeys=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for this question, I can add a note:
If you upload a file to a non-existing folder, it will be automatically created. There is no need to search for that.